# Deny GCP Marketplace Product

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, policy

I have a MarketPlace product Virtual Machine that i want to Deny in my organization.What is the correct way to do that i am not able to find any direct way to do that.

I tried creating organization policy but anyhow it didn't worked